# Two Listeners in Service (android)

Tags: android, listener, android-service

Firstly,sorry my English.And i am sorry about a large text.I just tried to describe in details.

A bit of my story:

> I am new in Android.I have some programming background(some Python,
>   some C++).I read a book about   Java, at First.Then I read a book
>   about Android(just a few pages =) )

So,the **goal** of my program:

Run in background(here i used Service) PhoneCallListener. When there is an incoming call, i use SensorEventListener, and do some magical things.

How I realized it:
...

```
public class mbackground extends Service{

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

then i try to use here "*public class phoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener{*"

And some methods of PhoneStateListener

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){ do some things }
```

Here i have a problem: for some reason, the compiler does not like **public** in definition class phoneCallListener...And then,how i can use Sensor Listener in one of the methods of  PhoneStateListener?

I tried to find information in Google. Honestly.

I do not know how to use Listeners correctly in that situation.I found some similar questions, but there Listeners used without class **extends** and some abstract methods.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onStartCommand`

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener();
```

should be

```
phoneCallListener phoneStateListener = new phoneCallListener();
```

Comment: **Hoan Nguyen**, thanks! I forget, what manager really do(bad that I almost did not read the book). Thanks that answer on stupid question and read a lot of text!)